# How disable direct call files on web dirrectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, nginx, apache2

My server was built on **Apache** and **Nginx**.
There are some directories with js scripts **Node** on root directory web site.
Via url address i can call direct file such like: *domen.com/node/notific.js*

How as it can be blocked?

I saw apache tutorial and found that it possible set in **apache2.conf**, to specify here in the Servername part param index-options, but it acts only on the prohibition directories.
And what you advice check me for more security my directories?

Thanks

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/php-files-browsable-is-this-a-vulnerability ?

Comment: Here describes only ban on folders, not files

Comment: Thank you, i found way to block direct call files.

Comment: Please post the answer here yourself. After a few days you can accept it and this question will no longer be an orphaned open question and might help others in the future.